# HasResolution typeclass

Tags: haskell

I just looked up the `HasResolution` [typeclass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Fixed.html#t:HasResolution) and it has a single method, `resolution` that is declared as follows:

```
class HasResolution a where
   ...
   resolution :: p a -> Integer
```

I don't understand the `p` in the above declaration.  Where does it come from and what does it mean?

Comment: It is universally quantified. The signature could be alternatively written `resolution :: forall p. p a -> Integer`. It means the caller of `resolution` can pick any `p` they wish, as long as `a` has a `HasResolution` instance.

Comment: `p` is what's often called a proxy type. The argument to `resolution` serves only to fix `a` to a particular type, indicating which `HasResolution` instance you want. The old-fashioned way to do this is to just take an `a`, but using a proxy is much clearer once you understand the idiom. `p` will often, but not always, be `Data.Proxy.Proxy`, an extremely boring type: `data Proxy a = Proxy`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's just a proxy.

If you had

```
class HasResolution a where
  resolution :: Integer
```

you'd get yelled at because there is no way for the compiler to ever infer *which* instance of `HasResolution` you want when you call `resolution`. Specifically, `resolution :: HasResolution a => Integer`, where `a` appears on the left but not on the right, so you can never infer `a`.

So, one solution was

```
class HasResolution a where
  resolution :: a -> Integer
```

and `resolution`'s documentation would say that it is not meant to inspect the `a`; it is just meant to let the compiler figure out which instance to pick. You'd use it as `resolution (undefined :: a)`. Then, another solution emerged:

```
data Proxy a = Proxy

class HasResolution a where
  resolution :: Proxy a -> Integer
```

`Proxy` gives no information to `resolution`; it exists, again, only for the compiler to infer what `a` is. It's better than the original in that `resolution` *really* can't inspect its argument, so the `Integer` is really associated with the type and not with the argument to `resolution`. It's slightly worse (or better, depending on who you ask) in that usage is the more verbose `resolution (Proxy :: Proxy a)` (you can't just use `undefined` because the implementation may pattern match on `Proxy`).

This evolved into

```
class HasResolution a where
  resolution :: p a -> Integer
```

This means that you aren't tied down to just `Proxy`, and it means that if you have, e.g., a `[a]` lying in scope, you can pass it to `resolution` without incurring massive verbosity, while maintaining compatibility with code that just used `Proxy`. Again, `resolution`'s first argument is for the compiler's use only. It means nothing to the actual implementation. You simply use it to select the instance of `HasResolution` you want.

`Proxy` eventually became so common that `GHC.Exts` got a new member: [`Proxy#`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/GHC-Exts.html#t:Proxy-35-). `Proxy#` has no runtime representation, so it incurs no performance penalty, unlike `Proxy` (or the above polymorphic `p` trick). `Proxy#`, however, suffers from the fact that its kind is `forall k. k -> TYPE (TupleRep '[])`. By not living in `*` like all the other "well-behaved" types, it cannot participate in the polymorphic `p` trick.

```
class HasResolution a where
  resolution :: Proxy# a -> Integer
```

The first solution is rather dated, though you see examples sometimes. The second and third are rather common, and the fourth was superseded pretty quickly by the most recent solution, which is to enable `-XTypeApplications -XAllowAmbiguousTypes` and just have

```
class HasResolution a where
  resolution :: Integer
```

again. `-XAllowAmbiguousTypes` staves off the error and `-XTypeApplications` lets you specify `a` at the call site as `resolution @a`. This can't be used in code that needs to be a certain degree of backwards compatible, but you see it more in libraries that require new GHC anyway and can afford to not have compatibility.

Comment: Thanks, @HTNW.  This is an element of the language I had not seen before and its history is interesting, too.

Comment: I think it's worth a small note that there is a second advantage to using a type variable for the proxy type - it prevents pattern matching. You can still pattern match on `Proxy`, even if it's a bit silly. But there's no pattern at all that can be used on a polymorphic type. Given this, the user of the code can look at the type and determine immediately that the argument is only be used to pass a type - it can't do anything else.

Comment: @Carl I don't think that makes much of a difference. You *still* can't pass `undefined` as argument for the polymorphic version, because `seq` (or, as I sometimes call it, pattern matching without the pattern matching) can still ruin your day. Granted, using `seq` on such an argument is absurd, but....