# Why are floatRange, floatRadix and floatDigits functions?

Tags: haskell, floating-point

According to [Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:floatRadix), these functions of the `RealFloat` class are

> ... constant function[s] ...

If they always remain at the same value, no matter the argument, as suggested by this description, why not simply use:

```
class (RealFrac a, Floating a) => RealFloat a where
    floatRadix :: Integer
    floatDigits :: Int
    floatRange :: (Int, Int)
    ...
```

Comment: How would you tell the compiler which type you were referring to like this?

Comment: If you use `floatRadix`, it would not be very clear if that is for a `Float`, or `Double`, etc.

Comment: In modern Haskell you could use explicit type applications (https://kseo.github.io/posts/2017-01-08-visible-type-application-ghc8.html) with your design: `floatRadix @Float`. But they were only added recently.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48798638/5684257

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `RealFloat` class is very old. Back when it was designed, nobody had worked out really good ways to pass extra type information to a function. At that time it was common to take an argument of the relevant type and expect the user to pass `undefined` at that type. As leftaroundabout explained, GHC now has extensions that do this pretty nicely most of the time. But before `TypeApplications`, two other techniques were invented to do this job more cleanly.

To disambiguate without GHC extensions, you can use either proxy passing or newtype-based tagging. I believe both techniques were given their final forms by Edward Kmett with a last polymorphic spin by Shachaf Ben-Kiki (see [Who invented proxy passing and when?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37261593/who-invented-proxy-passing-and-when)). Proxy passing tends to give an easy-to-use API, while the newtype approach can be more efficient under certain circumstances. Here's the proxy-passing approach. This requires you to pass an argument of some type. Traditionally, the caller will use `Data.Proxy.Proxy`, which is defined

```
data Proxy a = Proxy
```

Here's how the class would look with proxy passing:

```
class (RealFrac a, Floating a) => RealFloat a where
    floatRadix :: proxy a -> Integer
    floatDigits :: proxy a -> Int
    ...
```

And here's how it would be used. Note that there's no need to pass in a value of the type you're talking about; you just pass the proxy constructor.

```
foo :: Int
foo = floatDigits (Proxy :: Proxy Double)
```

To avoid passing a runtime argument at all, you can use tagging. This is often done with the `tagged` package, but it's quite easy to roll your own too. You could even reuse `Control.Applicative.Const`, but that doesn't communicate the intention so well.

```
newtype Tagged t a = Tagged
  { unTagged :: a }
```

Here's how the class would look:

```
class (RealFrac a, Floating a) => RealFloat a where
    floatRadix :: Tagged a Integer
    floatDigits :: Tagged a Int
    ...
```

And here's how you'd use it:

```
foo :: Int
foo = unTagged (floatDigits :: Tagged Double Int)
```

Answer (score 11):

Your proposed non-function methods would have type

```
floatRadix' :: RealFloat a => Integer
floatDigits' :: RealFloat a => Int
...
```

Those are *ambiguous types*: there is an `a` type variable, but it doesn't actually appear to the right of the `=>` and thus can't be inferred from the context. Which is, in standard Haskell, really the *only* way you can infer such a type variable: local type signatures also can only to the signature head, not the constraint. so whether you write `(floatDigits' :: Int)` or `(floatDigits' :: RealFloat Double => Int)`, it won't actually work – the compiler can't infer that you mean the `instance RealFloat Double` version of the method.

```
class RealFloat' a where
  floatDigits' :: Int
instance RealFloat' Double where
  floatDigits' = floatDigits (0 :: Double)
```

```
*Main> floatDigits' :: Int

<interactive>:3:1: error:
    • No instance for (RealFloat' a0)
        arising from a use of ‘floatDigits'’
    • In the expression: floatDigits' :: Int
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = floatDigits' :: Int
*Main> floatDigits' :: RealFloat Double => Int

<interactive>:4:1: error:
    • Could not deduce (RealFloat' a0)
        arising from a use of ‘floatDigits'’
      from the context: RealFloat Double
        bound by an expression type signature:
                   RealFloat Double => Int
        at :4:17-39
      The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    • In the expression: floatDigits' :: RealFloat Double => Int
      In an equation for ‘it’:
          it = floatDigits' :: RealFloat Double => Int
```

For this reason, Haskell does not allow you to write methods with ambiguous type in the first place. Actually trying to compile the class as I wrote it above gives this error message:

```
    • Could not deduce (RealFloat' a0)
      from the context: RealFloat' a
        bound by the type signature for:
                   floatDigits' :: forall a. RealFloat' a => Int
        at /tmp/wtmpf-file3738.hs:2:3-21
      The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    • In the ambiguity check for ‘floatDigits'’
      To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
      When checking the class method:
        floatDigits' :: forall a. RealFloat' a => Int
      In the class declaration for ‘RealFloat'’
```

The highlighted line cites however a GHC extension that says “it's ok, I know what I'm doing”. So if you add [`{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=ambiguous#extension-AllowAmbiguousTypes) to the top of the file with the `class RealFloat'` in it, the compiler will accept that.

What's the point though, when the instance can't be resolved at the use site? Well, it *can* actually be resolved, but only using [another pretty new GHC extension](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=ambiguous#extension-TypeApplications):

```
*Main> :set -XTypeApplications 
*Main> floatDigits' @Double
53
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem with this is that you would construct the functions for multiple instances, like:

```
instance RealFloat Float where
    -- ...
    floatRadix = 2
    floatDigits = 24
    floatRange = (-125, 128)

instance RealFloat Double where
    -- ...
    floatRadix = 2
    floatDigits = 53
    floatRange = (-1021, 1024)
```

But now it creates a problem when you query for example `floatDigits`: for what instance should we take? The one for `Float`, or the one for `Double` (or another type)? All of these are valid candidates.

By using an `a` parameter, we can make a disambiguation, for example:

```
Prelude> floatDigits (0 :: Float)
24
Prelude> floatDigits (0 :: Double)
53
```

but it holds that the value of the parameter does not matter, for example:

```
Prelude> floatDigits (undefined :: Float)
24
Prelude> floatDigits (undefined :: Double)
53
```